# Why do we need .lib file in case of importing functions from .dll?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, lib

Can you help me to understand, why do we need .lib files when importing functions and data from dll?
I've heard, that it contains a list of the exported functions and data elements from the corresponding dll, but when I used CFF Explorer to explore my dll, I found out that dll already has addresses of exporting functions so I theoretically can link my program with .dll without any additional files.
Can you, please, explain what kind of data is stored in the .lib files more detailed.
And, also, yes, I know, that visual studio forces us to add .lib files into additional dependencies section, but why does it really needs them?

Comment: Legit question. I am interested too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why some programs require both .lib and .dll to work...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602618/why-some-programs-require-both-lib-and-dll-to-work)

Comment: @MaxKunes are you searious right now? That is a completely different question, please read it before posting

Comment: @MaxKunes, I've already read some similar posts, so it don't answear my question. It just tells me what heppens, but there is no answer why It heppens.

Comment: Read [*linkers and loaders*](http://iecc.com/linkers/), a book by Levine. BTW, things a really different on Linux and most other Unixes

Comment: In fact, DLLs that export by name do contain all the necessary information.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/9360280/103167  However if the DLL exports by ordinal, the import library is the way to match names to ordinals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your source code *statically* calls exported DLL functions, or *statically* accesses exported DLL variables, those references are compiled into your executable's intermediate object files as pointers, whose values get populated at run-time.

When the linker is combining the compiler-generated object files to make the final executable, it has to figure out what all of the compiler-generated references actually refer to.  If it can't match a given reference to some piece of code in your executable, it needs to match it to an external DLL instead.  So it needs to know which DLLs to even look at, and how those DLLs export things.  A DLL may export a given function/variable by name OR by ordinal number, so the linker needs a way to map the identifiers used by your code references to specific entries in the `EXPORTS` tables of specific `.dll` files (especially in the case where things are exported by ordinals).  Static-link `.lib` files provide the linker with that mapping information (ie `FunctionA` maps to Ordinal `123` in DLL `XYZ.dll`, `FunctionB` maps to name `_FunctionB@4` in DLL `ABC.dll`, etc).

The linker can then populate the `IMPORTS` table of your executable with information about the appropriate `EXPORTS` entries needed, and then make the DLL references in your code point to the correct `IMPORTS` entries (if the linker can't resolve a compiler-generate reference to a piece of code in your executable, or to a specific DLL export, it aborts with an "unresolved external" error).

Then, when your executable is loaded at run-time, the OS Loader looks at the `IMPORTS` table to know which DLL exports are needed, so it can then load the appropriate DLLs into memory and update the entries in the `IMPORTS` table with real memory addresses that are based on each DLL's `EXPORTS` table (if a referenced DLL fails to load, or if a referenced export fails to be found, the OS Loader aborts loading your executable).  That way, when your code calls DLL functions or accesses DLL variables, those accesses go to the right places.

Things are very different if your source code *dynamically* accesses DLL functions/variables via explicit calls to `GetProcAddress()` at run-time.  In that case, static-link `.lib` files are not needed for those accesses, since your own code is handling the loading of DLLs into memory and locating the exports that it wants to use.

However, there is a 3rd option that blends the above scenarios together: you can write your code to access the DLL functions/variables *statically* but use your linker's *delay-load* feature (if it has one).  In that case, you still need static-link `.lib` files for each delay-loaded DLL you access, but the linker populates a separate `DELAYLOAD` table in your executable with references to the DLL exports, instead of populating the `IMPORTS` table.  It points the compiler-generated DLL references to stubs in your compiler's RTL that will replace the references with addresses from `GetProcAddress()` when the stubs are accessed for the first time at run-time, thus avoiding the need for the references to be populated by the OS Loader at load-time.  This allows your executable to run normally even if the DLL exports are not present at load-time, and may not even need to load the DLLs at all if they are never used (of course, if your executable does try to access a DLL export dynamically and it fails to load, your code is likely to crash, but that is a separate issue).

Comment: I understand that we need those addresses from .lib file, but why can't we figure out those addresses from the .dll. Doesn't it contains the same addresses? Because it`s kind of overhead to deal with more dependencies, isn't it?

Comment: @LexMarchenko I updated my answer with some more information about that. The linker can't just look at the DLLs. First off, it needs to know which DLLs to even look at, and then it needs to know how specific exports are defined. The `.lib` files provide such mapping information. They don't contain actual addresses at all.

Comment: At the end of the day I am using dll while running my application then why do we even need that lib in the first place

Comment: @pujadeo I covered that in my answer. See the 2nd and 6th paragraphs. Static-link import `.lib` files provide the *linker* with information it needs when figuring out which exports of which DLLs the executable will be using at runtime.

Comment: so liibs are like temporary intermidiate files right? then why don't we delete it as soon as we are done

Comment: @pujadeo static-link import `.lib` files are to DLLs, what `.obj` files are to source code files. They are just the precompiled code/metadata, which the linker can then reuse over and over each time you recompile the final executable. If a source file/DLL is changed, its obj/lib is updated, too.

Answer (score 1):

> I've heard, that it contains a list of the exported functions and data elements from the corresponding dll, but when I used CFF Explorer to explore my dll, I found out that dll already has addresses of exporting functions so I theoretically can link my program with .dll without any additional files.

As a trivial example of why this can't always work, consider an executable that accesses two DLLs, one for a Winsock filter and the other for an allocator. And say that on this particular machine, the Winsock filter DLL happens to also implement an allocator with the same API and the allocator DLL happens to also implement a Winsock filter with the same API. How could the compiler know which API functions to access from which DLL? The library file contains the *intent* in accessing the DLL, that is, the API and functions you want to access.

Importantly, there is no such thing as "The corresponding DLL". There might be different DLL files on different systems. What the linker needs to know is what the DLL is supposed to look like that it can rely on, not what the DLL that you might happen to use on some particular system might happen to be.

For example, suppose the DLL file contains an allocator. You might have one DLL file for an allocator with debugging, one for an allocator with optimizations for specific CPU versions, and one for an allocator that uses a new, experimental algorithm. What the linker needs to know is the API that all these DLL files implement, not the specific implementation in any one file.

You can [produce a LIB file from a DLL file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37760062/721269) but you might wind up building an executable that doesn't work when using some other version of the DLL file. You would have to assume that whatever this particular DLL happens to do is precisely what every other DLL that implements the same API will happen to do.

Comment: So, i assume, we don't actually need a .lib file, but it is more convenient to build with it, because we can be sure that a function with a given prototype actually exists somewhere in dll. And if it doesn't, we can generate a compile-time error instead of runtime error. Am i right?

Comment: We do actually need a .lib file. Otherwise, how would the compiler know *which* functions to use from *which* DLL? I think you're missing the point that a program using a DLL is using some particular API that DLL implements and that any number of other DLL files can implement that same API in different ways. There's no "one right DLL file" that will always be the one that is used. For system DLLs, for example, new versions of the OS will have new versions of those DLLs that can differ in radical ways but implement the same API. The LIB file documents the API.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The code base that I am working with generates both dll and lib files. However my software uses just the dll files. Then why did we generate libs at the first place?

Comment: @pujadeo the *application* doesn't use the lib file, the *linker* uses the lib file while compiling the application. Please re-read the answers again more carefully, you seem to be missing key information from them.